# Android Day and date in String format

Tags: android

How to display day and month in string format. I want to display day and date and month. Look like that

```
  Thursday
    11
   April
```

but when I used Calender class it returns date and day in different format just like `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: post the code you tried

Answer (score 1):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sString s= "2013-1-18";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM, dd ");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").parse(s)));
```